# opening a pop up window from an ahref link and passing data to the child

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a string, which, if clicked, opens up a pop up window. I am trying to set this up but I cannot seem to figure out what the best way to do this is.

1) I can use window.open after the onClick attribute.
2) I can call a JS function that opens up a dialog box.

I need to send data from the link to the popup window as it (the pop up window) will be using the string to query a database.

By reading other threads, I was able to come up with this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick=window.open('show.php','Ratting','width=650,height=270,0,status=0,');>
```

But using the above code, I can't seem to figure out how to send data to `show.php`.  I assume that sending data to `show.php` is similar to passing data in through a function 
eg: `show($data)`. But if this is so, where can this be placed in the a href attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first `.open()` parameter is just a URL like any other, so:

```
window.open('show.php?foo=bar&baz=qux', ...
```

lets you pass anything you want back as a GET query parameter.

Comment: Wow, that was simple... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the late binding in jquery and $.param you cand do in a js file:

```
$('#myPopUp').click(function() {
   var myParams = {
     param1: 'value1',
     param2: 'value2',
     .....
   };
   window.open('show.php?' + $.param(myParams),'Ratting','width=650,height=270,0,status=0,');
});
```

In your html:

```
<a id='myPopUp' href='javascript:void(0);'>
```